# List items to the right of a left floating div do not align properly

Tags: html, css, list, css-float

List item bullets do not align properly to the right of a left floating div. The minimal code goes like this:

```html
<div style="float:left; background-color:red;width:100px;">aa<br>bb<br>cc<br>dd</div>
<p>Title</p>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lg73hzfa/

Some suggestions from other posts and their drawbacks:

- Set `<ul>` display to table-cell. Problem is the whole list is pushed to the right without really floating under the `<div>`. https://jsfiddle.net/962m8egt/
- Add `position: relative;` and `left: 1em;` to `<li>`. The problem is that this brakes accessibilty to clickable items in right floating divs. Another problem is that a long item will overlap with the right floatin box. https://jsfiddle.net/nbx8g7tv/
- Set `<ol>` `list-style-position` to `inside` as suggested below but it brakes the alignment of the item content when it flow on more than one line. https://jsfiddle.net/15v9s0fg/

I need a solution that work even if the content is dynamic. Whatever the width of the div (which can be replaced by an image) or the length of the list. List items have to wrap to the left around the div when the list gets longer than the div.

Here is an example with an image: https://jsfiddle.net/15v9s0fg/1/

Thanks for any better suggestion?

Comment: Can you share an image showing what you want?

Comment: I just need the list to wrap properly around the left floating div or image and that the solution does not have the problems mentionned.

Answer (score -1):

The default `list-style-position` is `outside`, you can change it to `inside` for you case:

```css
div {
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
}

ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<div>
  aa<br>
  bb<br>
  cc<br>
  dd
</div>

<p>Title</p>

<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position

Comment: That's the third suggestion I wanted to add and is not acceptable to me because it brakes the alignment of the item content when it flow on more than one line. https://jsfiddle.net/15v9s0fg/

Answer (score -1):

The inline style of the div element is affecting the bullet points alignment.
So for that there are 2 ways so that the right side section does not affect.

- Remove the width applied to the div section from inline style

```html
<div style="float:left; background-color:red;">aa<br>bb<br>cc<br>dd
</div>
<p>Title</p>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

- Keep all the styles as it is and add height to that div of around 100px like,

```html
<div style="float:left; background-color:red;width:100px;height:100px;">aa<br>bb<br>cc<br>dd
</div>
<p>Title</p>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

So this will add a specific height to that section and the last bullet will come in proper alignmant

Comment: About the first case: I need a solution where the content of the div does not matter and is of fixed width. The div could be replaced by an image for example. <img src=https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ol6o8.png style="float:left;"/>

Comment: About the second case: The content is dynamic. This code is used anywhere in the site and the number of items can be different from one page to the other. No height will fixed them all.

Comment: Have you tried with the flexbox designing to align the data ? that will help you to manage the dynamic data designing as well

Comment: I have added flexbox based changes in this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/1jdnfgrt/15/ Please check

Comment: The div or the image is supposed to float and the list to wrap around them. In your flexbox example the div and the list are two rigid blocks seating side by side. Not an acceptable solution.